# Что такое статические методы в Delphi?

Tags: ооп, объекты, delphi, delphi-7, классы

В книге Хомоненко, Гофмана, Мещерякова написано:
По умолчанию все методы, объявленные в классе, являются статическими и вызываются как обычные подпрограммы.
Что такое статические методы в Delphi?

Answer (score 4):

Статические методы в Delphi - это не то же самое, что и статические методы в остальных ОО языках.

Методы, для вызова которых не нужен экземпляр класса в Delphi называются методами класса:

```
class function foo: string;
```

Все методы в Delphi по умолчанию статические. Если их пометить как `dinamic` или `virtual`, то такие методы могут быть переопределены в классе наследнике, заменяя их функционал.

Comment: >> Все методы в Delphi по умолчанию статические.

Уверенны?

Comment: Ну в книге Хомоненко, Гофмана, Мещерякова так написано :)

Comment: @_perchuk , а так все таки что такое статические методы? Это методы класса?

Comment: тут Delphi скорее всего имелось ввиду, что методы нельзя переопределить в наследниках. Интересен контекст, про что глава?

Comment: @_perchuk, "Cтатические методы везде одно и то же - методы, которые не относятся к объектам.(фактически глобальные функции/переменные)"

"Статические методы в Delphi - это не то же самое, что и статические методы в остальных ОО языках.
Методы, для вызова которых не нужен экземпляр класса в Delphi называются методами класса:"

Are you kiddin' me? Что по-твоему является экземпляром класса?

Comment: anObject = TMyObject.Creare();

TMyObject - класс,
anObject  - экземпляр класса

Comment: @_perchuk, я к тому, что экземпляр класса есть объект. Ты написал всё правильно кроме того, что отличается от других ОО языков. Во всех языках суть остаётся одна - есть доступ к методу без создания экземпляра класса(объекта).

>Статические методы везде одно и то же - методы, которые не относятся к объектам.

Comment: Да, тут путанница небольшая в терминологии. С точки зрения других языков статические методы это методы класса. А с точки зрения Дельфи статические методы - не абстрактные, не виртуальные, не динамические.

> Static methods: Methods are by default static.  
> (c) Delphi Help

И в D7 методов класса нет.

Comment: + тебе в карму и ауру

Comment: да, тут вопрос терминологии. все всё правильно написали

Comment: 1. В Delphi, кажется, начиная с Delphi 4, присутствуют методы класса (class methods). Но их количество в одном классе ограничено.
2. В Delphi в классе можно переопределить (redefine) любые доступные методы предка, а перекрыть (override) - только динамические (dynamic) или виртуальные (virtual).

Answer (score 1):

Статические методы везде одно и то же - методы, которые не относятся к объектам.(фактически глобальные функции/переменные).